# How to link shared libraries in custom path directly without specifying RPATH?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, rpath

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, and I am required to use an external library ([MCR](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr.html)). It puts all of it's shared libraries inside the `MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/` folder. I only need the libmx.so in there but there are libraries in there that has the exact same name as the ones in `/usr/lib` but they are actually different (because the file size is different), for example `libtiff.so.5`.

This becomes a problem because when I use the `find_library` function in CMake to add `MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/` into RPATH in order to link to libmx.so for my application, since my application also depends on another external library (OpenCV) that was linked to the `libtiff.so.5` in `/usr/lib` when it was built, when I compile my application it shows an compilation error of

> /usr/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.0: undefined reference to
>   `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'

It is because my application is trying to link to the `libtiff.so.5` in `MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/` instead of `/usr/lib` because RPATH has a higher priority than the default directories. What is the best way to solve this?

I tried renaming the `libtiff.so.5` in `MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/` to something like `libtiff_old.so.5`. This solves it but is very ugly.

Is there anyway I can alternate the search priority so RPATH goes after the default directories? Or is there something I can do in CMake so my application can directly link to libmx.so without having to add `MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/` into RPATH to mess things up?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first it would be good to see your cmake file, but alas..

You can try using this, the <...> is your base directory for the MATLAB install, which might be /usr/local/ or /opt.

```
find_library (MATLAB_RUNTIME libmx 
    PATHS <...>/MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
```

Comment: This is exactly how I use find_library in my cmake file. It's equivalent of adding this path to RPATH as verified by objdump.